# NVD3 Cumulative line chart displays wrong y values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have converted a line chart into a cumulative line chart and its y values are not displayed correctly. The range of the y axis should be 80.00 - 140.00 but instead I get -0.08 - 0.20. Has anyone managed to tweak their normalization code below to make it work with all kinds of ranges?

```
 line.values = line.values.map(function(point, pointIndex) {

   point.display = {
     'y': (lines.y()(point, pointIndex) - v) / (1 + v)
   };
   return point;

 })
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is somewhat old, but I am convinced that the normalization code for the cumulative line chart is not conceptually correct.  Furthermore, the NVD3 cumulative line chart implementation is actually an index chart implementation ([see Mike Bostock's example](http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/index-chart.html)).  A cumulative line chart would be more like [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/cumulative-tables-graphs.html), I think.  The cumulative chart can be easily achieved using the NVD3 line chart and some quick modifications to the underlying data.

If we take Bostock to be correct, and we really do wish to achieve an indexed line chart, then the indexify function in NVD3 should be changed to:

```
/* Normalize the data according to an index point. */
function indexify(idx, data) {
    if (!indexifyYGetter) indexifyYGetter = lines.y();
    return data.map(function(line, i) {
        if (!line.values) {
            return line;
        }
        var indexValue = line.values[idx];
        if (indexValue == null) {
            return line;
        }
        var v = indexifyYGetter(indexValue, idx);

        // TODO: implement check below, and disable series if series
        // causes a divide by 0 issue
        if ((Math.abs(v) < 1e-6) && !noErrorCheck) {
            // P.S. You may have to set a higher threshold (~1e-6?).
            // I don't know I didn't run any tests...
            line.tempDisabled = true;
            return line;
        }

        line.tempDisabled = false;

        line.values = line.values.map(function(point, pointIndex) {
            point.display = {
                'y': (indexifyYGetter(point, pointIndex) - v) / v
            };
            return point;
        });

        return line;
    })
}
```

I asked a [related question](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/695) to the authors of NVD3 and plan to submit a pull request.  **Note that percentage change charts are really only meaningful when all of the underlying data is positive.  When you start throwing negative values into the mix, percentage change loses all of its meaning.**

Answer (score 0):

What I found works is to insert another point with a y value of 0 at the beginning of the sequence of points.

Given a list of data points in the form [ [x1,y1], [x2,y2], ... [xn,yn]] ],
something like values.upshift([0,0]) works for me (the x value is arbitrary, but i just use 0 or values[0][0]) to insert to the front of the list.

(I'm getting the same thing with that chart. I'm still looking into it, but I hope this helped.)